# How to add custom deploy script in Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, app.yaml

I would like to deploy a php application to GAE. During the deployment though, I need to run custom scripts (Or add few commands). Is there a way to define scripts in app.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run custom scripts or commands before deploying to GAE, then the best approach would be using a custom runtime.

You will have to build a Dockerfile with a PHP base image and then run all your needed steps there. With this approach you will also be able to change the default entrypoint for the docker container.

The related documentation can be found in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).

Google also offers several [images](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#base), included a PHP one.